# Digital signature with node.js crypto

Tags: node.js, encryption, digital-signature

Could someone provide a basic walkthrough on how to implement digital signature with node.js? I've googled but didn't get it yet. Say, I have an API and I wanna sign and verify every http request to it and response from it. That's how I currently imagine it, plz correct me where I'm wrong:

1) I need to generate a random enough key for client, which will be used to sign requests;

2) Resulting signature (provided via header) is an encrypted with that key hash of a string, which has to include:

- hash of the request body (to prevent tampering);
- timestamp;
- nonce;
- url;
- HTTP verb

Then, the server would be able to check the authenticity of a message.

Questions:

1) What is the difference in this context between a nonce (some random value) and a timestamp (I've read a post where using both at the same time was advised)?

2) Do I need to include eTag header to that string?

3) What else, not listed above, should be included?

4) Should I keep the same key on the API server, as on client and decrypt and check requests with it, or should the key, stored on the API server, and the key, stored on the server, which communicates with API for a private-public keys pair? If they do need to be a private-public keys keypair, how do I decrypt what was encrypted with private key, using public key (and vice versa) in node?

Plz, correct what was wrong in my description and add, what I've missed. Thank you.

Comment: If you generate a asymmetric key pair on the client side, then you will need a secure channel to communicate the public key to the server.  If you already have a secure channel, then your system is unnecessary.  Your system doesn't really make sense or have a purpose?  Have a look at the TLS module of Node instead.  Far faster to implement and also far more secure than your design.

Comment: @LukePark The purpose is to create a mechanism that would allow the server to verify that a request is coming from somebody, who is known to the system (e.g. received an authorized api key), and also would allow the client to verify that response (or webhook) is really coming from that server, but not from some malicious source, trying to fake it. afaik,such approach is pretty common for public apis - you get an apikey, an apisecret, sign your requests, the server can verify them, and server also signs requests and responses and you can verify them. The question was - how to implement it right

Comment: Don't you think it would be easier to use TLS and JWT?  API keys are common yes, but digital signatures are slow.  Signing every single HTTP request is not common...

Comment: Take a look at Amazon REST Authentication to answer your question: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html. They require an authentication header calculated applying a HMAC hash on the request data. It is "signing the request".

Comment: @pedrofb Thank you. Could you, please, explain, is that secret, which developer uses to sign requests a shared symmetric key? Or does this algorhytm involve asymmetric keypair? If it's a shared key, would it make sense to use asymmetric keypair for such purposes? Like client has server's public key and own private key, server has own private key and client's public key, so they're able to sign and verify each other's requests. Would it create any additional security?

Comment: HMAC = symmetric, but an assymetric key makes sense. e.g. creating keypair at client side and sending the public key during registration. It is not needed that server signs the response. As propose @LukePark, just using TLS ensures server certificate validation and therefore authenticy (and channel privacity)

Comment: @pedrofb Thank you. so, basically, using HMAC involves a *single* key, known both to server and client? I'm a bit confused with this: http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/Hash-based-Message-Authentication-Code-HMAC explanation. Could you, please, comment on that? What `public and private keys` are they talking about there if there should be only one shared key?

Comment: I'm not sure what context this post is in. HMAC will use the same secret key to calculate the hash in both sides. May be it wants to talk about how to interchange the secret key between client and server using a public key infrastructure.  In any case the post it is confusing.

Comment: @pedrofb thank you so much for your effort! If I have e.g. 5 registered users of my api, each of them needs to have an api key and an api secret. api secret is the symmetric key, used to verify requests, while api key is a value, used to look up the proper api secret for each user(since it's different for each user). Do I get it right? If so, how could I store api secrets in a safe way? Isn't a db dangerous for that? Or maybe I should store encrypted api secrets instead of plain ones, encrypted with some master-key, held in ram?

Comment: All security solutions have a risk, even using HSM hardware. Consider risk-benefit. If you store the secret keys in DB, the system admin or someone who steals the DB password could get all of them. In some cases I've seen is used a master encryption key as you propose, stored in the machine (in fact some HSMs just store this master key)

Comment: I have summarized the content of the comments to provide a "consistent" answer. Please take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Amazon REST Authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) is good example to answer your question. AWS requires to "sign the request" applying a HMAC hash on the request data using a set of rules:canonicalization, encoding or timestamping. The signature is included in a Authorization header of the HTTP request

HMAC is a symmetric algorithm, client and server share the secret key, that is used in both sides to calculate the hash. If they match, then the request has been sent for an authorized party

An assymetric key also makes sense in this scenario. e.g. creating keypair at client side and sending the public key during registration. It is not needed that the server signs the response. Just using a TLS channel the client can trust in server validating server certificate ( TLS also provides channel privacity through encryption)

Using shared keys, it is needed to consider how to store secrets in a safe way, For example (as you propose), using a database, or encrypting secrets instead of plain ones with a master-key

All security solutions have a risk, even using HSM hardware. Consider risk-benefit. If you store the secret keys in DB, the system admin or someone who steals the DB password could get all of them. In some cases I've seen that is used a master encryption key stored in the machine (in fact some HSMs just manage this master key)

Comment: One solution to avoid security risk of storing keys in database as plain text, is to store key in db in encrypted form, you can use any external service to encrypt/decrypt key for you when storing/retrieving key from db.

Answer (score 11):

Below code sample uses `crypto` library(now built in with nodejs) to generate digital signature for a document.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

// See keys/README.md on how to generate this key
const private_key = fs.readFileSync('keys/privateKey.pem', 'utf-8');

// File/Document to be signed
const doc = fs.readFileSync('sample-doc.txt');

// Signing
const signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
signer.write(doc);
signer.end();

// Returns the signature in output_format which can be 'binary', 'hex' or 'base64'
const signature = signer.sign(private_key, 'base64')

console.log('Digital Signature: ', signature);
```

Here is the full code example from github : [digital-signature-for-document-signing](https://github.com/itsnuwan/digital-signature-for-document-signing)

Comment: Could it be possible to sign and add a plain placeholder in a pdf with crypto?